# jQuery menu used within queried output from MySQL?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am using a simple query to return rows from a database table in the following format:

```
<div class="<?php echo ($accept == '1')?'showop':'show';?>">
<span class="namecustcoltype"><?php echo $record;  ?></span>
<span><a href="#" class="decline" id1="<?php echo $id1; ?>">
<input type="button" title="menu" value="Decline" /></a></span>
</div>
```

Essentially this produces rows that look like this:

```
<linked div> record from table     button</linked div>
<linked div> record from table     button</linked div>
<linked div> record from table     button</linked div>
```

I need to add a jquery dropdown menu to the button (it doesnt have the be a button; it could also be a link that is styled to look like a button). Ive tried numerous solutions and have two main issues:

1. positioning doesn't work - the ending div tag is right next to another container and the menu must overlap the two (the container the rows are in and the one next to them.
2. I need to pass variables from each row to the menu items - The concept here is each menu must be linked to each row and make it possible to pass items like rowid from the query through the menu and to an AJAX call that updates the table based on the specific selection made from the menu.

Most of the jquery menus cannot be located within the query div and this prevents passing any info from the query to the outside calls via the menu.

BTW css dropdown menus force a horizontal scroll bar within my query container - already tried that.

Im up for any ideas or solutions you may have including procedures other than dropdowns. I have five selections that need to be made when a user clicks on the button in each row so let me know your thoughts!

Thanks

Comment: please format your code that its readable!

Comment: This looks like an interesting issue, but I'm not really sure what you need. Can you give us the exact functionality? Do you want a popup to show with hover? Are all of the data from the php call to be hidden in the div, then shown on hover? What happens when you click the button?

Comment: Thanks for your comments; Ill clarify my issue. The row is just that...a simple row with a record and a button. The button allows a user to 'accept' the info presented in the row. Two things happen when the button is clicked: A: The record in the table is updated (this is functional already) and B: the user is presented with a menu of 'choices'. The choices represents reasons why they accepted the data. When a user chooses a reason from the menu, the table is updated with the reason they accepted the record. Thats why the menu HAS to be associated with the record!